# Command inside another command - Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, date

I know how to run a simple command inside another command, but in my case is special. My command contains `"` (`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`).I need to display my log via 1 command.

If I do this `date "+%Y-%m-%d"` I will get `2020-06-03`. I want to pass that command into another command like this:

```
tail -f /Users/jdoe/Sites/laravel7/storage/logs/laravel-"date "+%Y-%m-%d"".log
```

I can't to get it working. How do I do it?

#### Expected

To run this command

```
tail -f /Users/jdoe/Sites/laravel7/storage/logs/laravel-2020-06-03.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

```
tail -f /Users/jdoe/Sites/laravel7/storage/logs/laravel-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").log
```

An older deprecated syntax uses backticks

```
tail -f /Users/jdoe/Sites/laravel7/storage/logs/laravel-`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.log
```